# Docker compose: pass the random container port to environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to set in the docker compose file the container information about NetworkSetting into the environment variable?

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  sdt-proxy:
    image: myimage
    ports:
      - 32770-32780:8181
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8181
```

It maps the port 8181 to a random port from 32770-32780. when I run the container with `docker-compose up`, I can see the mapped port with `docker inspect`:

```
.....
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "83e6933aaf7b09b8ae1238d3dbb71bdd495c14927a5a509b332afc17cda6d854",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8181/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "32771"
                    }
                ]
            },
...
```

So, I know that the internal port 8181 (my application running inside the container), is mapped to the port 32771.

I need to pass this information, the container port 32771 to my application, is it possible to do something like this in the docker-compose file?

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  sdt-proxy:
    image: myimage
    ports:
      - 32770-32780:8181
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8181
      - MY_CONTAINER_PORT= <the running container port 32771>
```

Comment: Why does the thing inside the container need to know what port things outside the container see it on? What other services are in that `docker-compose` file, and how do they connect to the `sdt-proxy`?

Comment: If your application lives in another container you start with the same `docker-compose up` command, it can access the service directly on `sdt-proxy:8181`. Other than that, the answers to @jonrsharpe 's comment would be interesting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sdt-proxy application needs to push this information to another host service (think like it's a service register).